# Getting error when running music bot, discord rewrite

Tags: discord.py

I get an error in one of my cogs. I believe it is talking about the attributes guild not being in discord.client:

```
File "/Users/me/Desktop/Personal Coding/Music-bot-forward/bot.py", line 27, in <module>
    bot.add_cog(Player(client))
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/Personal Coding/Music-bot-forward/music.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.setup()
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/Personal Coding/Music-bot-forward/music.py", line 19, in setup
    for guild in self.bot.guilds:
AttributeError: module 'discord.client' has no attribute 'guilds'
```

The tutorial:https://youtube.com/watch?v=46ZHJcNnPJ8&feature=share

The code:https://pastebin.com/abgvsD29
I am new to the Discord.py library and do not really understand the docs either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason being was in my code,`await ctx.voice.channel.connect()` You would need to replace that with `await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()`.